# scrapy and mysql

Tags: mysql, scrapy

I am trying to get scrapy to insert crawled data into mysql and my code crawls fine and collects the data in the buffer, does not error, but database is never updated.
'no luck', 'no error'

pipeline.py

```
from twisted.enterprise import adbapi
import datetime
import MySQLdb.cursors

class SQLStorePipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.dbpool = adbapi.ConnectionPool('MySQLdb', db='craigs',
                user='bra', passwd='boobs', cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor,
                charset='utf8', use_unicode=True)

    def process_item(self, items, spider):
        # run db query in thread pool
        query = self.dbpool.runInteraction(self._conditional_insert, items)
        query.addErrback(self.handle_error)

        return items

    def _conditional_insert(self, tx, items):
        # create record if doesn't exist.
        # all this block run on it's own thread
        tx.execute("select * from scraped where link = %s", (items['link'][0], ))
        result = tx.fetchone()
        if result:
            log.msg("Item already stored in db: %s" % items, level=log.DEBUG)
        else:
            tx.execute(\
                "insert into scraped (posting_id, email, location, text, title) "
                "values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                (items['posting_id'][0],
                items['email'][1],
                items['location'][2],
                items['text'][3],
                items['title'][4],
                )

            )
            log.msg("Item stored in db: %s" % items, level=log.DEBUG)

    def handle_error(self, e):
        log.err(e)
```

crawl code

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from craigs.items import CraigsItem

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "craigs"
    f = open("urls.txt")
    start_urls = [url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]
    f.close()
    rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('/html/body/blockquote[3]/p/a',)), follow=True, callback='parse_profile')]

    def parse_profile(self, response):
        items = []
        img = CraigsItem()
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        img['title'] = hxs.select('//h2[contains(@class, "postingtitle")]/text()').extract()
        img['posting_id'] = hxs.select('//html/body/article/section/section[2]/div/p/text()').extract()
        items.append(img)
        return items[0]
        return img[0]
```

settings.py

```
BOT_NAME = 'craigs' 
BOT_VERSION = '1.0' 
SPIDER_MODULES = ['craigs.spiders'] 
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'craigs.spiders' 
USER_AGENT = '%s/%s' % (BOT_NAME, BOT_VERSION)
```

Comment: Try putting a print statement in your `process_item` and `_conditional_insert` functions to see if either of them get called. Also, what does your settings.py file look like?

Comment: settings.pyBOT_NAME = 'craigs'
BOT_VERSION = '1.0'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['craigs.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'craigs.spiders'
USER_AGENT = '%s/%s' % (BOT_NAME, BOT_VERSION)

Comment: misc print statements in pipelines.py never reflect the code being executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `COMMIT` the current transaction,  which making changes permanent.

So after

```
tx.execute(\
            "insert into scraped (posting_id, email, location, text, title) "
            "values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
            (items['posting_id'][0],
            items['email'][1],
            items['location'][2],
            items['text'][3],
            items['title'][4],
            )

        )
```

you have to

```
db.commit()
```

`db` here is something like

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user = "root", passwd = "1234", db="database_name")
```

Please try it.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the pipeline code is not being called at all is because it hasn't been activated. This activation is done by adding a new section to settings.py, as per the [Item Pipelines page in the documentation](https://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/0.16/topics/item-pipeline.html#activating-an-item-pipeline-component). e.g

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = [
    'craigs.pipeline.SQLStorePipeline',
]
```

Additionally, your `parse_profile` function should just return `img`. You'd only add an items list to return if a single response page would result in multiple items.

Comment: Edited answer following a suggested edit by Akhter Wahab. Cheers dude!

Answer (score 1):

activate Pipeline in settings and use yield instead of return